# Post on the active user's wall

Tags: facebook, post, dialog, feed

I want my app/website to post on the active user's wall (likely as the status) that should look like the following image:

[image]

If I use the "feed dialog", i am not able to post custom header like **USER gave a gift on APP**
as in this image.

Also, after *about an hour ago* , i am getting  **via APP_NAME** if I use Feed Dialog

Pls help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible via feed dialog. You need to use Open Graph actions to accomplish this.

See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/