# Posts made to page wall displayed in user newsfeed without "via <application name>"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, feed

Posts made to page wall using graph api displayed in user newsfeed without "via ".
You can see axample here http://www.insidefacebook.com/2012/11/12/new-link-shows-users-more-page-posts-and-friend-activity-in-news-feed/.
Is it possible to see what application shared this post to page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post on the active user's wall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841060/post-on-the-active-users-wall)

Answer (score 0):

The "via"-attribution for posts done by apps on pages was recently dropped by Facebook.
I'm pretty sure there's no way to tell from the outside, if a post was made through an app, and which app in particular.

Compare this screenshot of what the Graph API exposes about a post (its a post we've published on http://fb.com/diesocialisten via http://www.swat.io)

Post: https://www.facebook.com/129842310398883/posts/350825491682109

There's no hint of the used app here:

[image]

Anvesh is right: you actually can get the "application"-field, but you have to query the feed itself (/diesocialisten/feed), not the particular post. Cool, didn't know that!

Comment: Forgot to say that I already looked posts at wall and page using Graph API Explorer. As you say there is no "application" attribute for page posts, but user wall posts have it. My problem that page posts made from app using graph api displayed in user newsfeed without "via..." and can have it(or not. why I dont know) if I look at the same posts on page wall.

Comment: Yeah, that might be a bit inconsistent. Afaik Facebook is just transitioning & removing the "via" for pages...

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use Graph API to find out what application created the post. Although Michael is correct in pointing that **via-** tag is removed by Facebook on post's display.

[image: Application that created that post]